# Two times password required for booting

Tags: greeter, security, keyring

My version is Freya, and I chose encryption of my harddisk at the installation. 
The whole HDD is used with one root partition and one swap partition.

The first time it asks for password is just after running BIOS:
"Unlocking the disk /dev/disk/by-uuid/...{a very long number comes here}....(sdb5_crypt)"  "Enter passphrase:______________________"

The secong time is at the welcome screen.

In the Security & Privacy settings I have disabled both locking options.

1. Is there any way to automatically pass at least the first login, maybe both?
2. What happens if I choose Delete of the login password in the keyring manager?

Thanks, Børge

Comment: Hi Borge, you can remove the need for the second password by going to the user's configuration and enable auto-login. The first password is to unlock the HD, as you instructed the installer to do.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior. If you have enabled disk encryption, you'll need to enter your password to unlock the disk or the computer won't be able to boot.